# How to ping a server from another remote IP using the command line

Tags: unix, command-line, ip, ping

A client of mine says they're not able to connect to the site and I would like to check if they can ping the server their site is on, obviously I'd want to do it myself rather than explain how to do that to them.

**How do I ping my server if I have both my server's IP address and the remote client's IP address in Mac's Terminal?**

It doesn't have to be the Terminal app either, I would much prefer an answer that was available for any UNIX machine.

I'm expecting something like this:

```
ping www.example.com from 123.45.678.901
```

Comment: is ssh based solution acceptable?; e.g. opening ssh for that ping command and closing it

Comment: @JossefHarush but would I not be able to receive the packets being sent back to that IP address? How would you do it?

Comment: in which direction you want to ping? client -> server / server -> client?

Comment: it's not possible to force other computer to make a ping request (without an opened shell). **you should do the opposite direction** (server -> client) since you own the server and have shell access to.

Comment: @JossefHarush but will that tell me if there are connectivity issues with that specific client? I'm trying to see if the connection is healthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can not, unless the customer allows you to his network by some means. At max you can ping your site from some ping test web site (just google "ping test" or similar)

Comment: Is there no shady way to mask my IP as the remote client while I ping the target server? Now that I think about it, my request seems kinda insecure to do so easily.

Comment: There are shady ways to mask your IP. But that won't prove connectivity to the target from the desired remote.

Answer (score 0):

`ping -c 3 <url/ip>`(substitute `<url/ip>` with whatever you have, works on any Unix Terminal)

Comment: Which value is the target IP and which is the value that represents the remote client?

Comment: It is **only** the target IP/url. If you want to ping from a remote client/with a remote IP, you need to login to that client, e.g. via `ssh`.

Comment: Yea that's what I thought